# Datatable Onclick in dynamic row won't run?

Tags: datatable

I can add row dynamically with this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var t = $('#entryJurnal_table').DataTable({});

var delete = function (){

    //this function won't run
    //delete selected row code goes here

}

$('.add').on('click', function () {


          var credit = '<td><input type="numeric" name="kredit[]" class="form-control"></td>';
          var debit = '<td><input type="numeric" name="debet[]" class="form-control"></td>';

          var opt= '<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" onclick="delete()">Delete row</a></td>';


          t.row.add($('<tr>' + credit + debit + opt + '</tr>')[0]).draw();

        });
});
```

How I can delete row dynamically?

When I click `Delete Row` it say `delete is not defined`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you think about [row().remove()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove()) method?

Comment: how I can call thus method if, onclick function doesn't work? title edited . Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use *event propagation* instead of defining handlers within `onclick` attribute.

```
$('#entryJurnal_table').on('click', '.del', function() {
  t.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).remove().draw();
});
```

**Note**, it uses `.del` class for delete button. And if the `<a>` elements are used to act as buttons, then they should also be given an appropriate `role="button"`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @alexander

add row with array

```
table.row.add(['input tag', 'input tag', 'delete button tag with delete class']).draw();
```

delete row with this

```
$("#entryJurnal_table tbody").on("click", ".delete", function () {      
      t.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
});
```